# How does the car still work if the mummy in "The Kingdom of the Crystal Skull" is so magnetic?

Tags: indiana-jones

If the mummy case was magnetic enough to pull around all the wrenches and metal parts and lamps and guns etc., then why is the car that they put it on still able to drive? The metal parts in the engine would be be pulled towards it. Sure they have aluminum and other alloys but at the time I'm pretty sure car engines would be mostly cast iron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse the case was magnetic and pulled loose metallic objects. Loose means that they were not coupled or attached to anything else.

Car engine as a whole have several smaller parts but they are coupled together to stay together and not fly off. Definitely magnetic effect would be there on the car but once engine is propelled the force of it would be greater than the magnetic force.

In worst case it might slow down the car. But for stopping it, it would take much more than a 6 feet strong magnet.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense

Comment: @StrBoP: You should wait for more answers with other possible explanation to come in before marking this as correct one. In such case upvoting is good.

Comment: Yep but I’m doubting anyone else will answer.

Comment: @StrBoP: In that case you can upvote and accept.